# Exporting variable to multiple files and use as property string

Tags: javascript, node.js

What I want/need is to send a base url to every file which is going to be concatenated with the rest of the full path that I already have as a property of another object, but when I try to use the path, I get an invalid URL message.

I have this on the *sender*:

```
const urlBase = 'http://example.com/';
module.exports = urlBase;
```

This is what I have on the *receiver*:

```
const urlBase = require('../file.js'); //I know the path is correct here
module.exports = {
    scenario: [{
            label: 'first situation',
            url: urlBase + 'situation1.html',
            }], 
};
```

There are reasons why I have to have everything on module.exports in the end and all the properties and so on, but could that interfere? What am I doing wrong or what should I do? It works fine if the full path is on the url property, but since it can change, depending if I am on localhost or not, I needed it.

Comment: The code you've posted looks fine to me, so the error must be coming from somewhere else. Could you post the full error?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for reviewing my question and your comment. I found the solution with some other help.

Answer (score 0):

So, with some help, I did things differently and it worked like this:

Sender:

```
module.exports = { baseUrl: 'http://example.com' };
```

Receiver:

```
const urlBase = require(../file.js).baseURL;
```

and kept the rest as it was.

See the **.baseUrl** on the last line? That did the trick.